# Generate a distribution in python with given mean and std

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I'm trying to create a distribution with given mean and std.
But I can't generate a distribution with exact mean and std.
For example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
group = np.random.normal(loc=10,scale=5,size=50)
print(group.std(),group.mean()) # 5.62761460277423 10.702796361565493
```

I need exact mean and standard deviation that I put into brackets. Which function do I need to use to create a distribution with fixed mean and std instead of .normal

Comment: You will approach the desired mean and standard deviation as your sample size increases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean of the group is 10 and the std 5 if you take `size` to infinity. At the moment, you are drawing `size=50` samples. You will get closer to the desired values as you increase the value of `size`.

```
>>> group = np.random.normal(loc=10,scale=5,size=50000)
>>> print(group.std(),group.mean())
5.000926728104604 9.999396725329085
```

Comment: Yes I see. Do you know the way to create a distribution with the same mean and std as I put into brackets despite the size of the array. For example, I want to create an array with mean 10 std 5 and size 20, how can I handle it? need exactly these values no more no less

Comment: Tom271 has answered this below, please upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

To follow from  forgetso's answer (which follows from the [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)), to shift your random sample so that it has the exact mean and standard deviation, you can [standardise the values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) to mean 0 standard deviation 1 and then shift it to your desired values

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> group = np.random.normal(loc=10,scale=5,size=50)
>>> print(group.std(),group.mean())
5.62761460277423 10.702796361565493
>>> group_standardised = (group - group.mean()) / group.std()
>>> print(group_standardised.std(),group_standardised.mean())
1.0 -6.483702463810914e-16
>>> desired_std = 5
>>> desired_mean = 10
>>> group_scaled = group_standardised * desired_std + desired_mean
>>> print(group_scaled.std(),group_scaled.mean())
5.0 9.999999999999996
```